Migration from Newtonsoft.Json to System.text.Json
I have some C# reflection code module that is passed in a C# Object that contains dynamic properties. The module looks for properties in the object and if found, calls them passing in json data tailored for the property.
One of the parent applications uses System.Text.Json (Net 8) and the Code module uses NewtonSoft.Json.
I'd like to make a copy of the module so I have one using Newtonsoft and the other using System.Text.Json.
For the most part this is doable, with the exception I can't find an alternative for the following NewtonSoft code  (NewtonSoft.Json.Linq).
IEnumerable<JToken> JContainer.Descendants()...

Exampe: var jobjKey = jojb.Descendants().Where(t => t.type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)t).Name == propertyName).Select(p => new {((JProperty)p).Name, ((JProperty)p).Value}).FirstOrDefault().

and
JEnumerable<JToken> JToken.Children()

Example: var jArr = JobjKey.Value.Children(); foreach(var item in jArr)...

Is there a suitable alternative to these two items?

For some reason there is no equivalent to JContainer.Descendants() in System.Text.Json.  You can find one at How to recursively descend a System.Text.Json JsonNode hierarchy (equivalent to Json.NET's JToken.DescendantsAndSelf())?.  Does that answer your question?  Or do you need a precise rewrite of the code shown?  If so can you share a [mcve] with a JSON sample and the expected output?
